# Building a PDO MYSQL query from a php arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to build a query from the values of an array so far I have,

```
$itemPlus = $_POST['itemPlus'];
$query = implode(', ', array_map(function($items) {return $items . ' = ' . $items . '-?';}, $items));
// $query = 'hats = hats-?, gloves = gloves-?, scarfs = scarfs-?'
$params = implode(', ', $userCost);
// $params = '10, 7, 9'
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE items SET " . $query . ", $itemPlus = $itemPlus+1 WHERE id = ?");
$q -> execute(array($params, $account['id']));
```

It doesn't work, this is my first time trying this and as it doesn't work I am obviously doing something wrong!?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Please don't use `$_POST` variables (or any other user input) directly in your query.

Comment: Read this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

Comment: @drrcknlsn it isn't vunerable to squal at all.

Comment: `$itemPlus = $itemPlus+1` is vulnerable.

Comment: @cgwebprojects:  The `$itemPlus` variable is injected directly into the query string, and `$itemPlus` is just `$_POST['itemPlus']`.

Comment: @webbiedave thanks, I'll take my question as a yes seeing as you didn't answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$params` is a string of values, you cannot make it into an array along with `$account['id']`. Instead.use the array that created it `$userCost`:

```
// Start with the $userCost array...
$paramArr = $userCost;
// Add $account['id'] to it
$paramArr[] = $account['id'];
// And pass that whole array to execute()
$q -> execute($paramArr);
```

Since `$itemPlus` is coming from `$_POST`, you will need to be sure that is valid input. Since it refers to a column name, it is recommended to use a whitelist for that:

```
// Check against an array of possible column names:
if (!in_array($_POST['itemPlus'], array('col1','col2','col3','col4',...)) {
   // $_POST['itemPlus'] is NOT VALID
   // Don't proceed...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I can see now why it didn't work and it is now thank you.

Comment: @cgwebprojects Please also see the part I just added about validating `itemPlus` with a whitelist of possible column values...

Comment: Wouldn't the query just fail if thr column was not found?

Comment: @cgwebprojects Yes in some cases it will fail, but it also leaves you open to SQL injection if a malicious value is passed into $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (one of them) lies here:

```
$q -> execute(array($params, $account['id']));
```

The `$params` variable is a comma-delimited string:

```
// $params = '10, 7, 9'
```

You want to pass an associate array of params and values to the `execute()` method, like this:

```
$params = array(
    'hats-?' => 10,
    'gloves-?' => 7,
    'scarves-?' => 9
);

// ...

$q->execute($params);
```